# How to assign multiple UIButtons to a UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to assign two UIButtons to UITextView so that when one of the buttons is pressed the textview content should change from what it had when the previous button was pressed.

Comment: assign a selector method to both of the buttons.... then in those method set the text property to the value which u want to display when the correspondin button is pressed..Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

MyViewController.h:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString* savedText;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView* textView;

- (IBAction)buttonOnePressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)buttonTwoPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

Connect the view controller's textView outlet to the text view in the xib file. Connect the buttons to the corresponding actions. (See Apple's Xcode tutorial if you don't know how to do this.)

MyViewController.m:

```
- (void)buttonOnePressed:(id)sender
{
    [savedText release];
    savedText = [textView.text copy];
}

- (void)buttonTwoPressed:(id)sender
{
    textView.text = savedText;
}
```

(These aren't the complete files, of course, just the bits to make it do what you're asking.)